# How to inject multiple dependencies in constructor?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am doing unit testing.And i have a controller which is depended on multiple repositories(means there are multiple dependencies).

Below is the piece of code of controller :-

```
public class TestController : BaseController
{
  //Declaring dependencies 
   private IProductService _productService;
   private IStudenctService _studentService;
   private ITeacherService _teacherService;
   private IClassService _classService;
   private ITaxService _taxService;
   private ICategoryService _categoryService;
   private ISchoolService _schoolService;
  //Constructor calling…
   public TestController ()
   {

   }

   public TestController (IProductService productService)
   {
       this._ productService = productService;
   }
   public TestController (IStudenctService studenctService)
   {
       this._ studentService = studenctService;
   }
   public TestController (ITeacherService teacherService)
   {
       this._ teacherService = teacherService;
   }
   public TestController (IClassService classService)
   {
       this._ classService = classService;
   }
   public TestController (ITaxService taxService)
   {
       this._ taxService = taxService;
   }
   public TestController (ICategoryService categoryService)
   {
       this._ categoryService = categoryService;
   }
   public TestController (ISchoolService schoolService)
   {
       this._ schoolService = schoolService;
   }
  public TestController (ISchoolService schoolService, ICategoryService categoryService)
   {
       this._ schoolService = schoolService;
       this._ categoryService = categoryService;
   }
   public TestController (ISchoolService schoolService, ICategoryService categoryService, ITaxService taxService, IClassService classService)       {
       this._ schoolService = schoolService;
       this._ categoryService = categoryService;
       this._ taxService = taxService;
       this._ classService = classService;
   }
}
```

In the above code i have made separate constructor for each dependencies.Where there 2 constructor taking multiple arguments(dependency arg).

By this my unit test method is working well. But when i run application then its giving me below error :-

> **Uh-oh, something went wrong! Error Code: 500**

But when i call only one parameter constructor then its working.Can anyone let me know what is wrong here ? What should do in case of multiple dependencies ?

Comment: Error code 500 has nothing to do with Unity I think the erorr coming not from depeandecy injection the error shall be somewhere else

Comment: Configure Visual Studio to break on all exceptions (by going to Debug/Exceptions... and checking both the 'Thrown' and 'User-unhandled' checkboxes of the 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions' line) and see what exact exception pops up. ALWAYS post the exception details with your question.

Answer (score 4):

If these are dependencies of your class, then you should have a single constructor that takes all of the dependencies as parameters.

In other words, you can not instantiate to a valid state without all of your dependencies.  They are not optional, they are *dependencies*.

I would start with taking this approach, and then ask a separate question if your application still throws an error.

Comment: ,initially i used that approach(having only one constructor with all dependencies) but it was giving the same error while calling that controller.But the unit testing was doing properly.

Comment: I absolutely agree. There should [always only be one constructor](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Comment: @Pawan In the code you posted, there is a default (parameterless) constructor. This leads me to think that you might not have your own controller factory implemented. (That is, if your class has dependencies, and defines a constructor to pass them in, then it *shouldn't* have a parameterless constructor because those dependencies will be initialized to `null`.) Details of implementing a controller factory can be found here: http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2008/10/10/asp-net-mvc-tip-dependency-injection-with-structuremap.aspx